# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined Graphql, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I've got the following error message with my code:

> field.arguments.forEach(collectNode);
>                               ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

```
newPedido: (root, {input}) =>{
            const newPedido = new Pedidos({
                pedido: input.pedido,
                total: input.total,
                fecha: new Date(),
                cliente: input.cliente,
                estado: "PENDIENTE"
            });

            newPedido.id = newPedido._id;
            return new Promise((resolve, object) => {
                input.pedido.forEach(pedido => {
                    Productos.updateOne({_id : pedido.id}, 
                    { "$inc":
                        {"stock" : -pedido.cantidad}
                            }, function(error) {
                            if(error) return new Error(error)
                        }
                    )
                });

                newPedido.save((error) => {
                    if(error) rejects(error)
                    else resolve(newPedido)
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: input.pedido is not array type Please debug first and check on which you want to make a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `input.pedito` exists and is an array before iterating on it:

```
newPedido: (root, {input}) =>{
            const newPedido = new Pedidos({
                pedido: input.pedido,
                total: input.total,
                fecha: new Date(),
                cliente: input.cliente,
                estado: "PENDIENTE"
            });

            newPedido.id = newPedido._id;
            return new Promise((resolve, object) => {
                if (input.pedito && input.pedito.length > 0) {
                    input.pedido.forEach(pedido => {
                        Productos.updateOne({_id : pedido.id}, 
                        { "$inc":
                            {"stock" : -pedido.cantidad}
                                }, function(error) {
                                if(error) return new Error(error)
                            }
                        )
                    });
                }

                newPedido.save((error) => {
                    if(error) rejects(error)
                    else resolve(newPedido)
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Si gustamente tenias razon se me habia pasado ver en el Schema como lo estaba declarando, gracias :D